# Sequelize's dynamic set/get methods for assoctiations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

The only reference in Sequelize's documentation that I could find about this  is at [Relations / Associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/).

Apparently, if you have something like:

```
Person.hasOne(Person, {as: 'Father', foreignKey: 'DadId'})
```

then you can do something like:

```
Person.setFather();
Person.getFather();
```

As far as I understand, these set and get methods are created dynamically for associations.

However, I have tried something similar and it does not work:

```
Person.hasOne(Father, { foreignKey: 'father_id' });

var aPerson = Person.build({
    name: 'Mike'
});

aPerson.setFather({ id: 1 });
```

I realized that the `{ id: 1 }` bit may not be correct, but the problem is that I get a message saying that the setFather function is `undefined`.

Basically, my question is: how can I attach associations to an already-created instance of some model in Sequelize?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a specific model for fathers? The associations uses the model name, which means to just importing the user model as Father is not going to work:

```
var Person = sequelize.define('person')

var Father = person;

Person.hasOne(Father) // adds setPerson
Person.hasOne(Person, { as: 'father'  }) // adds setFather
```

I recently updated the API docs for associations - hopefully it should be a bit clearer which functions are added and what parameters they take http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/has-one/

Comment: I do have a `Father` model, I just forgot to copy/paste it. Obviously, this is just an example, my real code is different and also more complicated. However, this may inspire me. I'll try it and comment here if I still don't get it. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you cannot pass a plain JS object to the set function, either pass a sequelize instance (`father.build` / `find`) or pass the primary key directly `setFather(1)`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant when I said that `aPerson.setFather({ id: 1 });` might not be correct. Mentioning `setFather(1)` is very useful, thanks! I find the Sequelize documentation a bit lacking in certain areas, so it's hard to tell what should happen without looking at the code. Can't check the main question at the moment, will do so later. Once again, thank you!

Comment: I have looked around in Sequelize's code and it seems that it does create the getters and setters properly, but I still can't access them, which leads me to believe that I am doing it wrong. I have something like `var instance = Person.build({..})` and then I try `instance.setFather()`. Is this the wrong way to do it?

Comment: That looks correct to me. Try to log `Person.Instance.prototype` - There you can see which methods are on the person instance